# getType in wordnet java API

Tags: java

I am using wordnet java API.
I have defined a

```
WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordForm);

System.out.println("type " + synsets[i].getType());
```

when I do this print, I get value 1 for "new york".

I am trying to find the value is NOUN (or) Verb....
But I get this values as 1.
what does 1 stand for?

It says [here](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/doc/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/SynsetType.html) is of type: SynsetType.

Please let me now how I can find if the given word I give to lookup  and the response is a noun (or) verb..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This time I misread the documentation :) I suggest using this:

```
SynsetType type = synsets[i].getType();
if (type.equals(SynsetType.NOUN)) {
    // Code for nouns
} else if (type.equals(SynsetType.VERB) {
    // Code for verbs
} else {
    // Code for non-verb/nouns.
}
```

Comment: but it is not working. it gives,incompatible operand type synset and int

Comment: its complaining that the "cannot switch a value of type synset type . only coverable int values (or) enums can be used?

Comment: should we do something else like converting it ?

Comment: @Kishore: Darn, I'd assumes it was an enum type. No switch then, but comparing with == or (possibly more robustly) `equals` is probably okay. I've edited my answer now.